# The PHP define value is lost in include files

Tags: php, variables

I have a config.php file with this line in it:

`define("home_dir",'soft06/site_name');`

In index.php file I have:

```
include_once ("config.php")
... some html code ....
include_once (home_dir."/footer.php")
```

That works well.
However if in footer.php I put this line:

```
echo("home_dir=".home_dir);
```

I get:

```
Notice:  Use of undefined constant home_dir - assumed 'home_dir' in <b>D:\xampp\htdocs\footer.php on line 3
home_dir=home_dir
```

But if I choose to include footer.php like this:
`include_once ("footer.php")` instead of `include_once (home_dir."/footer.php")`
It works fine.

It seems to me that if I use the constant home_dir in include_once function I will lose the home_dir value within the include file.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: change `include_once (home_dir."footer.php")` in `include_once (home_dir."/footer.php")`

Comment: Or more "precisely", `include_once(home_dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."footer.php")`.

Comment: sorry about that it is include_once (home_dir."/footer.php") I just forgot to type it in the question above. I have made the corrections in the question asked.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? Try not to use relative paths if possible. You can use the `__DIR__` constant in 5.3+ to make sure your home_dir path is pointing to the right location.

Comment: Let's not view this like a path issue but let's just consider the define value like a simple string. Because the problem is not in the inclusion of files (include_once works perfect) but why the value of home_dir is lost inside the file included?

Comment: in index.php, can you write `var_dump(defined('home_dir'));` after config inclusion? what's the output? I think that config.php is included wrong

Comment: So, are there two different `footer.php` files?

Comment: it is only one footer.php but if I include it like this: include_once (home_dir."/footer.php") then the home_dir value is lost inside the footer.php but if I do this: include_once ("footer.php") it is all ok

Comment: @Laxus the output is bool(true) inside the index.php and inside the footer.php. But if I use include_once (home_dir."/footer.php") then the output is bool(false) inside the footer.php and bool(true) inside the index.php

Comment: How is it possible that `D:\xampp\htdocs\footer.php` is the same file `soft06/site_name/footer.php`?

Comment: @sectus: soft06/site_name/footer.php is the url address and D:\xampp\htdocs\footer.php is the Physical address on the HDD. Just remember that it is NOT a problem of including footer.php. The file is included fine and displayed fine in the browser. However the value of the home_dir constant is lost inside the footer.php file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you

```
include_once (home_dir."/footer.php")
```

trying to include file over http :^ ) And it have been executed before inclusion. So footer.php running in another http request and there for home_dir was not defined.

You must use local path for including.

Comment: This seems to me like the right answer. Thank you for your help.