# php 5.4 define function

Tags: php, include, constants

I used to have a config file in PHP that `define`'d some constants. It doesn't seem to work anymore since upgrading to PHP 5.4.

Here's an example:

```
//config.php
define('CONSTANT', 'foo');

//page.php
require_once 'config.php';

echo CONSTANT; //not defined
```

Comment: I get expected output when running 5.4

Comment: Please post the actual code as well, not just the examplary excerpts.

Comment: [Similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15111022/the-php-define-value-is-lost-in-include-files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think your config.php file is being properly included, or is properly defining the constant. `define()` works the same way in php 5.4 as it did before.

After you include your config file and expect the constant to be defined, use `get_defined_constants()` to see what you've got. That's helpful with debugging issues with constants.

Comment: thanks! i did so and found out my `config.php` was not being properly included because the `php.ini` file was overwritten (and included a different `include_path`).